# How to create stack bar chart with setdata object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have JSON data as

```
{
  "data":[
    { "month" : "January",
      "name" : "John",
      "count" : 10
    },
    {
      "month" : "January",
      "name" : "Jane",
      "count" : 15
    }
  ]
},
{
  "data":[
    { "month" : "February",
      "name" : "Mark",
      "count" : 20
    },
    { "month" : "February",
      "name" : "Max",
      "count" : 30
    }
  ]
}
```

example here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked

How reference setdata object to stack bar chart?
I try `console.log(setdata[0]['data'][0]['month']);`
return "January" it's works find but

```
for(i=0 ; i<result.length ; i++){
  console.log(setdata[i]['data'][i]['month']);
}
```

It's error.

Comment: you are missing a ",", after the value of "name"  you need a comma.

Comment: Your `JSON` is invalid. Verify the `JSON` here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: what is `setdata` here?

Comment: var setdata = [{
            data: [ ]
          }];

Comment: Please create [a live demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - e.g. in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the d3 stacked bar chart-

```
let innerColumns = {
  'column1': ['value3'],
  'column2': ['value1', 'value2'],
};

let dataset = d3.layout.stack()(['value1', 'value2', 'value3'].map((value) => {
  return data.map((d: any) => {
    return { x: obj[d.xAxis], y: d.value };
  });
}));

let x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map((d) => { return d.x; }))
  .rangeBands([0, width], 1);

let y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, (d) => {
    return d3.max(d, (d1) => { return d1.y0 + d1.y; });
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);
```

For more: 
https://github.com/amanjain325/angular-d3-charts/tree/master/src/app/multi-bar-chart